# How to Create a use defined Event and send it?

Tags: iphone, events

flocks, Is there anyone could help me ? i want to send a use defined event and get it in iphone. how to create a use defined event in iphone development?

Comment: What is a "use defined event"?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Notifications by "use defined event", you should check this out:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html